# How to inject dependencies when testing an AngularJS Service using $injector

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a service I wrote but the service includes the `$http` module. How can I inject a dependency into a module that was retrieved using `$injector` for a service provided by the module?

Below is the sample code:

**Service**

```
var app = angular.module('myServiceApp', [])
.service('CommonService', ['$http', CommonService]);

function CommonService($http) {
  var Service = {};
  // ...code
  return Service;
}
```

**Testing Code**

```
describe('My Common App', function() {
  var Service;

  beforeEach(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector('myServiceApp');
    Service = $injector.get('CommonService');
  });
});
```

**Error**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24httpProvider%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20CommonService
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ng mock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock)?

```
var service;

beforeEach(mocks.module('myServiceApp'));
beforeEach(mocks.inject(function (CommonService) {
    service = CommonService;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following instead:

```
beforeEach(module('myServiceApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_CommonService_) {
  CommoService = _CommonService_;
}));
```